# Оптимизировать код сайта, чтобы получить его превью в WYSIWYG-редакторах социальных сетей

Tags: seo, html, разметка

Доброго времени суток.

Когда мы вставляем ссылку на сайт, в `WYSIWYG`-редактор социальных сетей, иногда мы получаем превью сайта:

[image]

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как оптимизировать код своего сайта, чтобы получить его превью при вставке в `WYSIWYG`-редакторы социальных сетей?

Сдается мне, дело в разметке.

Мне хватит ссылок на статью или названия технологии, чтобы погуглить.

**UPD:**
В конечном итоге разобрался с несколькими "пердставлениями" семмантической разметки.
Я адаптировал страницу в соответствии с http://schema.org/ и http://ogp.me/
Так же добавил стандартные:

```
<meta name="title" content="тайтл">
<meta name="description" content="дескрипшн">
```

Не уверен в том, какая социалка что схватывает, но думаю, что лишним не будет :).
Фэйсбук понимает ogp. Вконтакте вроде достаточно стандартных meta title и meta description.

**Подводные камни:**
Фэйсбуку в качестве превью-изображения нужна картинка не менее 200x200 px.

**klopp**, **void**, спасибо за ответы!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как вариант - можно сделать скриншот, "записать в картинку", а потом подставлять с помощью

```
<meta property="og:image" content="http://www.site.ru/images/screen.jpg" />
```

Answer (score 1):

[Мне нравится (Like Button (Facebook)), картинка в привью. Как заставить показываться нужной картинки](http://strivingfor.info/notes_mne-nravitsya-button-facebook-kartinka-v-privyu-kak-zastavit-pokazyvatsya-nuzhnoj-kartinki/)